# Как работать с файлами на внутреннем носителе телефона?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Мне надо создать файл ( типа мини бд ), но я не хочу его создавать на sd карте, а хочу в папке с приложением, куда всё устанавливается. Сколько не просмотрел статей на тему чтение и запись, все стараются на sd. Я пытался записать файл как ресурсный, но потом с огорчением понял, что ресурсные файлы программным кодом изменять нельзя. И вот опять  вернулся к теме, что надо создавать файлы. Прошу помочь с грамотным созданием файла и его чтением. Спасибо.

Comment: используйте getExternalFilesDir внутри можно передать подпапки если нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте каталог `context.getFilesDir()` - пишите в этот каталог. Он будет писать во внутренний каталог приложения, на который никаких пермишен не нужно, примерно так:

```
File myFile=new File(context.getFilesDir(), "myfile.txt");
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало! Если можно то вопрос не по этой тебе по касается разработки приложения) я почему то не могу найти директорию своего приложения (пробовал устанавливать и апк ) типа com.название.... с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Один пост - один вопрос. Выставляйте вопрос - вам ответят